# How to include source map for CSS minification scritpt created by gulp task?

Tags: css, gulp, package.json

I am working on minification of CSS using gulp.

Problem is when I need to debug CSS, I see all css are in `knx.dev.css`, 
but I need to build a solution when do inspect element it can lead to original file from where it has been generated

**package.json**

```
{
    "main": "index.js",
    "dependencies": {
      "gulp": "^3.9.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
          "gulp-bundle-files": "^1.9.5110",
          "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
          "gulp-cssmin": "^0.2.0",
          "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2"
    },
    "scripts": {
          "build": "gulp",
          "start": "gulp dev_css"
    }
}
```

**Gulp task**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var css_file_list = [
  //List of files];

gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.src(css_file_list)
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
        .pipe(concat('knx.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
gulp.task('dev_css', function () {
    gulp.src(css_file_list)
        .pipe(concat('knx.dev.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@muneer-alam your idea works but I have found another way using `gulp-sourcemaps`

so for `knx.dev.css` gulp build I have changed gulp build as below

```
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
.
.
.
gulp.task('dev_css',function () {
  return gulp.src(css_file_list)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('knx.dev.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

It give me a source map i.e. going to proper file when I do inspect element.

Answer (score 2):

Please use gulp-sourcemaps for this. It can be used for many jobs. These can be found here. https://github.com/gulp-sourcemaps/gulp-sourcemaps/wiki/Plugins-with-gulp-sourcemaps-support . When using inspect in chrome, instead of seeing "styles.min.css", you will see "styles.css" and also the line number that style came from making it much easier to debug your css. I started using sourcemaps about a month ago and haven't turned back.

I use it alot for compiling scss to css. In my chrome inspect, I see the original styles.scss and line number instead of the styles.css it compiled it to so i know where the issue is in my scss file.

Definitely check out gulp sourcemaps. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

You'll love yourself so much more :)

> EDIT

To expand on Ramratan's answer, where you pipe `.pipe(sourcemaps.write())`, here you can specify where you want your .maps files to go if you don't want them in the same folder as your compiled CSS folder.

> UPDATE #2 for more clarity.

Right now you have >

```
gulp.task('dev_css', function () {
    gulp.src(css_file_list)
        .pipe(concat('knx.dev.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

> install gulp sourcemaps with npm i --save-dev gulp-sourcemaps
>   Require the sourcemaps at the top of your gulp file
>   var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

Now change your dev_css task to >

```
gulp.task('dev_css',function () {
  return gulp.src(css_file_list)
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('knx.dev.css'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('Name of destination folder'));
});
```

At this point in time, Where ever your gulp.dest points to, that is where your concatenated css file and sourcemap file will be put.

So you might see something like.
-CSS folder 
 --knx.dev.min.css 
 --knx.dev.css.map

The map file is what tells google chrome where the original knx.dev.css file is. That's how it knows what line is causing issues and what line number it came from in the original file.

For example.

In chrome, Instead of seeing.

```
Line 1 from knx.dev.min.css
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

You will see.

```
Line 200 from knx.dev.scss
    body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }
```

Hope this makes sense!

Also as far as the changing the destination of the map file, if your only using that one css file, don't worry about changing the map files to a different location. This only makes sense to change the destination of the map files if your working with a bunch of css files.

So for the sourmapswrite pipe

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
```

Just keep the period right there, that tells sourcemaps to put the map file right in the same folder that your css file is going in. This will make it less confusing for right now.

Hope this helps.

So all in all, you don't need to use the append, prepend method that was suggested if you just use gulp-sourcemaps. It's totally up to you though! :)

Comment: can you explain more ...`if you don't want them in the same folder ..`, with current solution with mine answer, source map is appended to `knx.dev.css` in last, you mean to say I can specify new path rather than append?

Comment: No problem, ill update my original answer in a minute. You don't have to use the append prepend method that was mentioned. That is extra work that is not needed when using gulp sourcemaps, ill update my answer in a few minutes with more details

Comment: Updated my original answer for you.

Comment: Will look on Tue, as now office hour is over and I have long weekend in India, :), I got your point.

Answer (score 1):

This is not javascript so you can not get exact feature, but you can use [this to append and prepend file path](https://github.com/urish/gulp-add-src).

```
.pipe(addsrc.prepend('files/js/constants.js'))  // we use `addsrc.prepend` to add our .js files to begining of the SRC array
.pipe(addsrc.append('files/js/conflict.js'))    // we use `addsrc.append` to add our .js files to end of the SRC array
```

and in CSS files you can add comment like which file its after every 200 lines, so while navigate in `knx.min.css` you can know in which file you need to change CSS.